# A question in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Considering the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$ { f }(x)=\begin{cases} 0\quad ,\quad x \in [0,1)  \\ 1\quad ,\quad x=1\end{cases} $$

I am trying to show that $L(f,P)=0$ for any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$

I know the following applies to $L(f,P)$

$$
L(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \inf_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)
$$

I have been given a hint that the

$$\inf_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)=0$$

for any arbitrary interval P. But I am not quite sure how to show this and then conclude that $L(f,P)=0$.

Comment: What is your problem in seeing that this infimum is indeed zero for each closed (non-degenerated!) interval? This is in fact trivial.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I am not quite sure how to explain why this inf is zero for each closed interval. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: @fr14 to prove this you only need to see that the image of $f$ (see the definition of $f$) is the set $\{0,1\}$, and for any not empty sub-interval of $[0,1]$ exists a point where $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that the inf is zero, just check the definition.

> **Definition:** The inf of a set, $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is the unique number $x$ that satisfies:
>
> 1. $\forall s\in S, x\leq s$
> 2. $\forall y\in\mathbb{R},(\forall s\in S, y\leq s)\Rightarrow y\leq x$

In words, $x$ is the inf of a set if and only if it is the greatest lower bound.

Clearly the function is bounded below by $0$, and since it actually equals zero it can't be bounded below by any larger number.

$a\cdot 0=0$ and $0+0=0$ so the summation is $0$.

Comment: so using the definition that the inf is the greatest lower bound of the set we can say that the inf of this set is 0?

Comment: and so then $$
L(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \inf_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)
= \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i)  (0)=0$$??

Comment: @fr14 Yup! That's right

Comment: thanks for your answer, last question then I will accept your answer. I see that the function is bounded below by 0, but what do you mean when you say since it actually equals 0

Comment: @fr14 On every interval $(a,b)\subseteq(0,1)$ there exists a point $x\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x)=0$. That's how you know that there can't be any larger lower bounds.

Comment: are those brackets in the last comment supposed to be () or []?

Comment: @fr14 oh, I thought you had some intervals in terms of (). Ultimately it doesn't matter, because it's true both with () and with []

Comment: so the answer remains the same I just need to say that on every interval $[a,b]$ is s subset of $[0,1]$ there exists a point $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$

Comment: @fr14 Yup, that's right.

Comment: awesome, thanks for your help!